# Not able to delete selected row from table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a table in which i insert rows dynamically with edit/delete link for each row.
Edit row is properly working but when it comes to delete it always deletes the first row.

Here is the code:

```
  <table ng-model="Employee" border="1">
      <thead>
          ..
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
           <td>{{emp.id}}</td>
            ..
           <td><a href="#" ng-click="EditRow(emp);">Edit</a>&nbsp &nbsp<a href="#" ng-click="DeleteRow(emp);">Delete</a> </td>

         </tr>
       </tbody>
 </table>
```

corresponding controller code:

```
 $scope.DeleteRow=function(emp) {

    $scope.employees.splice(emp,1);

}
```

It always deletes the first row.Plz help me.

Answer (score 4):

Pass the index in delete function,

*HTML*

```
<td><a href="#" ng-click="EditRow(emp);">Edit</a>&nbsp &nbsp<a href="#" 
       ng-click="DeleteRow($index);">Delete
</a> </td>
```

*JS*

```
DeleteRow($index);

$scope.DeleteRow=function(index) {

    $scope.employees.splice(index,1);

}
```

in Splice method you need to pass First Index and then How many element you need to delete,

```
splice(2,1)
```

Check the Details about the method @ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: Thanks.. its working... but even with emp i was passing the same index na... then why didnt it work?

Comment: Emp is an object not a Index